# Copying / preserving symbolic link timestamp

Tags: linux, freebsd, touch

I have been working on some projects on a GNU/Linux system and now they have been archived on a FreeBSD server. In the archive, I have rearranged some directories and now I noticed that some symbolic links are broken: They point to paths that existed on my development laptop but do not exist in the archive. So, I would like these links to point to the new location where the target directory has been archived. I would like to keep all timestamps of files, directories and symbolic links unchanged.

My plan was the following:

**Step 1**

Copy the timestamps of the symbolic link and of the containing directory using touch:

```
$ touch -r . /tmp/timestamp-folder
$ touch -h -r ./symlink /tmp/timestamp-symlink
```

**Step 2**

Remove and recreate the symbolic link with the correct path:

```
$ rm symlink
$ ln -s <correct-path> symlink
```

**Step 3**

Restore timestamps:

```
$ touch -h -r /tmp/timestamp-symlink symlink
$ touch -r /tmp/timestamp-folder .
```

Unfortunately, this did not work.
First of all, `touch` refuses to read the timestamp of a symbolic link if the target does not exist:

```
$ touch -h -r symlink /tmp/timestamp-symlink
touch: symlink: No such file or directory
```

So I tried creating the missing path (directory) so that touch can read the symbolic link. This time `touch` ran without errors but the created file `/tmp/timestamp-symlink` has the timestamp of the directory pointed to by the symbolic link, not that of the symbolic link itself.

Is there a way to use `touch` to just read out the timestamps associated to a symbolic link and set them on another file, in the same way as for ordinary files and directories? If not, is it possible to achieve this using other tools?

Comment: This works for me regardless (whether the destination exists). Something is not right on your end. Maybe an old version of coreutils.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Here is my version: `touch (GNU coreutils) 8.30`

Comment: Maybe I have found a solution. On GNU/Linux, I first have to create the file where I want to save the timestamp with `touch /tmp/timestamp-symlink`. then I can run `touch -h -r symlink /tmp/timestamp-symlink` and this sets the timestamps on the existing target file. On FreeBSD, it still won't work, but I guess FreeBSD does not use coreutils so the behaviour may be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On FreeBSD, the GNU version of `touch` is in the `sysutils/coreutils` package.

```
$ sudo pkg install sysutils/coreutils
```

After installing that package, you should have the `gtouch` utility in `/usr/local/bin`.  Add that directory to your `PATH` if it isn't already present.

```
$ ls -l $(which gtouch)
-r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  133144 Apr  6 18:19 /usr/local/bin/gtouch
```

My testing suggests that your comment about creating the `/tmp/timestamp-*` files ahead of time is correct.  Other than that, using `gtouch` in lieu of `touch` in your code seems to work, so perhaps this example will help:

```
gtouch /tmp/timestamp-folder /tmp/timestamp-symlink

gtouch -r . /tmp/timestamp-folder
gtouch -h -r ./symlink /tmp/timestamp-symlink

# Remove and recreate the symbolic link with the correct path:

rm symlink
ln -s <correct-path> symlink

# Restore timestamps:

gtouch -h -r /tmp/timestamp-symlink symlink
gtouch -r /tmp/timestamp-folder .
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know that I could use the GNU version of touch under FreeBSD!